# How to include duplicate keys in HashMap?

Tags: java

I need linked and  multiple keys in key set. I tried this:

```
LinkedHashMap<Integer, String> map = new LinkedHashMap< Integer,String>();

map.put( -1505711364,"4");
map.put(294357273, "15"); map.put(-1593134417, "28"); map.put(-1231165758, "45");
map.put(121046798, "58");
map.put(294357273, "71"); map.put(-1593134417, "82"); map.put(-1231165758, "95");
map.put(121046798, "108");
```

I need duplicate keys which is order preserved. What is the way to do this??

Answer (score 38):

You can't have duplicate keys in a `Map`. You can rather create a `Map<Key, List<Value>>`, or if you can, use [Guava's `Multimap`](https://guava.dev/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html).

```
Multimap<Integer, String> multimap = ArrayListMultimap.create();
multimap.put(1, "rohit");
multimap.put(1, "jain");

System.out.println(multimap.get(1));  // Prints - [rohit, jain]
```

And then you can get the `java.util.Map` using the [`Multimap#asMap()`](https://guava.dev/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html#asMap--) method.

Comment: will insertion order is preserved in this one??

Comment: @vijji It doesn't hurt to try it out :)

Comment: The order of key insertion won't be preserved with `ArrayListMultimap`; you might want `LinkedListMultimap`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman. But what's the meaning of the very 2nd line of the ArrayListMultimap doc? Also, when I tried inserting different keys, it was giving out the keys in the insertion order. Am I missing something?

Comment: @RohitJain: 1) The meaning is that the values for a given key are kept in insertion order, but the keys themselves might not be kept in insertion order.  `ArrayListMultimap` is like a `HashMap<K, ArrayList<V>>`, not a `LinkedHashMap<K, ArrayList<V>>`.  You got lucky with your test data, that insertion order was preserved.

Comment: @LouisWasserman. Oh. Thanks. It's clear now :)

Comment: How can we find the duplicate pair? from multimap

Answer (score 21):

Use `Map<Integer, List<String>>`:

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> map = new LinkedHashMap< Integer, List<String>>();

map.put(-1505711364, new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("4")));
map.put(294357273, new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("15", "71")));
//...
```

To add a new key/value pair in this map:

```
public void add(Integer key, String newValue) {
    List<String> currentValue = map.get(key);
    if (currentValue == null) {
        currentValue = new ArrayList<String>();
        map.put(key, currentValue);
    }
    currentValue.add(newValue);
}
```

Comment: Then to add a value for an **existing** key one will need `get`, `concatenate`, and `put`, right?

Comment: @PM77-1 just `get` the `List<String> list` and call `list#add(theNewString)`.

Comment: @PM77-1 I've updated the answer to show that. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you write `Arrays.asList(new String[] { "15", "71" } )` instead of `Arrays.asList("15", "71")`?

Comment: @Holger I forgot the method accepts a varargs...

Comment: 1. Why am I getting `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException` at this step `currentValue.add(newValue);` ?


2. How does it come we update `currentValue` after adding it to `map` ? will this actually change the `map` ? Aren't we supposed to put the `currentValue` in the `map` again

Comment: @Radhwen fixed.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Great ! Now can you please answer my second question ?

Comment: @Radhwen since the value is a mutable list, then what you only need to do is to update the state of the list. If the list is immutable (as it was before), then in that case you would need to update the map by updating the value in that key.

Answer (score 14):

`Map` does not supports duplicate keys. you can use collection as value against same key.

> Associates the specified value with the specified key in this map
> (optional operation). If the map previously contained a mapping for
> the key, the old value is replaced by the specified value.

[Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put%28K,%20V%29)

you can use any kind of  `List` or `Set` implementation according to your requirement.

If your values might be also duplicate you can go with `ArrayList` or `LinkedList`, in case values are unique you can use `HashSet` or `TreeSet` etc.

---

Also In [google guava collection library](https://github.com/google/guava) [`Multimap`](https://guava.dev/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) is available, it is a collection that maps keys to values, similar to Map, but in which each key may be associated with multiple values. You can visualize the contents of a multimap either as a map from keys to nonempty collections of values:

```
a → 1, 2
b → 3
```

Example -

```
ListMultimap<String, String> multimap = ArrayListMultimap.create();
multimap.put("a", "1");
multimap.put("a", "2");
multimap.put("c", "3");
```

Comment: Does HashSet support this?

Comment: No. HashSet does not.

Comment: how will you remove from this multimap with key?

Comment: `Multimap#removeAll(Object key)` - Removes all values associated with the key key.
`Multimap#remove(Object key,Object value)` - Removes a single key-value pair with the key key and the value value from this multimap, if such exists. If multiple key-value pairs in the multimap fit this description, which one is removed is unspecified.

Answer (score 1):

`hashMaps` can't have duplicate keys. That said, you can create a map with list values:

```
Map<Integer, List<String>>
```

However, using this approach will have performance implications.