# Mocking Duplicate keys in LinkedHashMap java

Tags: java, collections, linkedhashmap

I have read some of the questions ([one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35129071/map-which-allows-duplicate-key-as-well-as-maintain-insertion-order/35129417#35129417),[two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35129071/map-which-allows-duplicate-key-as-well-as-maintain-insertion-order)) regarding having duplicate keys in the `LinkedHashMap`. But I have a specific requirement to handle a scenario in legacy code.

I have `LinkedHashMap<String,String>` in the code, I need to modify the code to support duplicate Keys. I created below class

```
public class StringContainer {
    private String data;

    public StringContainer(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.data;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return 10;
    }
}
```

And modified the code to `LinkedHashMap<StringContainer,String>`. Now my code works fine as I broke the `equal()` method by not overriding. Is this approach is fine? Any hidden issues I will face (other than performance)?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just replace the map with something more appropriate? Like a `List` for example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What happens if we override only hashCode() in a class and use it in a Set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26302169/what-happens-if-we-override-only-hashcode-in-a-class-and-use-it-in-a-set)

Comment: I assume this is not possible because of legacy code (although this would be the best solution). Are you sure that your code works now? iirc `HashMap` use the `hashCode()` method to determine the keys. So by setting the hash code to a fixed number you probably can not create a hash map with more than one value. Also I don't think that this is a very good solution because other people may rely on `equals` and `hashCode` to be working as they are intended.

Comment: @MarkusK Yes code is working fine in prod,You can store multiple values with same key