# How can I get the Specifics values from Map<String, List<String >>

Tags: java, list

In Java, I am implementing this:

```
Map<String, List<String >> mdaps = new HashMap<String, List<String >>();
```

I want to display the list that contains the word "Scored" like this:

```
Scored [Profile]
Scored [Applicability]
```

But how to search in `entry.getkey()`?

as it does not work with: `if(entry.getKey().contrains("Scored"))`

**Here is my code:**
**Edit1**

```
Map<String, List<String >> mdaps = new HashMap<String, List<String >>();

          List<String > List1 = new ArrayList<String>();
          List<String > List2 = new ArrayList<String>();
          List<String > List3 = new ArrayList<String>();

          List1.add("Profile");
          List2.add("Applicability");
          List3.add("Level 1");

      mdaps.put("(Scored)", List1 );
      mdaps.put("(Scored)", List2 );
      mdaps.put("Not Scored", List3 );

      for(Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : mdaps.entrySet()){

              if(entry.getKey().contains("(Scored)")) // not Working
          System.out.println(entry.getKey()+" "+ entry.getValue());
      }
    }
```

[**DemoProgramm**](http://ideone.com/BN8ibo)

thanks in advance.

Comment: `contrains` -> `contains` ??

Comment: try   entry.getKey().equals("Scored"). you have add two item with same key. but it will replace first item

Comment: 1. The code contains another bug: you are overriding `List1` with `List2` when you insert it using the same key into `mdaps`. 2. Use Java conventions when you're naming variable: List1 --> list1 and etc. 3.Try to give a more meaningful names to your variables.

Comment: Have you even looked at the page that you linked yourself? ("DemoProgramm" link) It clearly shows at the bottom: `Main.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
              if(entry.getKey().contrains("(Scored)"))`

Comment: A `HashMap` can hold only unique keys - so when you `put` `List2` after `put`ting `List1`,  `List1` gets replaced by `List2` in the map. Also, the method is called `contains`, not `contrains` (note the absence of the 'r'). You'd want what we call a `MultiMap`, which allows for multiple values per key - and you can find details of one at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18922165/how-to-include-duplicate-keys-in-hashmap

Comment: Thank you to you, the problem is solved :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Are Over writing the value of key "(Scored)" by putting again using the same key . So List1 is not displaying in sysout. You should not use same key  for different values. 
HashMap uses hasCode() of key to  store the values and String having same value will have same hascode. and it thinks that its the same. hence over writes the value.

Answer (score 1):

entry.getKey() will return a set and that will contain your key so it will always return true.

```
for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : mdaps.entrySet()) {

            if (entry.getKey().equals("Scored")) // not Working
                System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue());
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what if the line contains the word "(Scored)" or not?

Comment: what ever you want to your key to satisfy you can put.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to replace contrains by contains:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : mdaps.entrySet()) {

            if (entry.getKey().contains("(Scored)")) 
                System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue());
        }
```